# FlutterFlow: Refresh the list of firestore on back press

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, flutterflow

On my home screen, I have a list of loan data fetched from Firestore with pagination, displaying 10 items per page. There's also a button to create a new loan. After creating a loan and back to Home screen, I'd like to refresh the list, but I'm unsure how to achieve this using FlutterFlow.

I've enabled "Listen for changes" in Firestore, but it appears that it only listens for updates and not for item additions or deletions.

How can I implement this refreshing mechanism in FlutterFlow?

Comment: Hi I have updated my answer as per your query can you check ?

Answer (score 1):

As per the FlutterFlow's docs of **[Infinite scroll on a list from the Firestore collection](https://docs.flutterflow.io/widgets-and-components/widgets/layout-elements/listview#infinite-scroll-on-a-list-from-the-firestore-collection)** it is stated as :

> On enabling the infinite scroll, the Listen For Changes property also gets enabled. That means the list automatically updates if changes are made to the item. This is done to keep all the items up to date on the screen. However, it does not update the list if any new item is added or deleted. In rare cases, you would need to disable this feature. To do so, turn off this property.

To fix this you have to rebuild the list from its source while you are done creating the document.

#### Update :

- You can [Add Refresh Database Request button](https://docs.flutterflow.io/actions/actions/backend-database/refresh-database-request#adding-refresh-database-request-action) to fetch the latest changes or new document creates.
- Or You can use [Single Time Query](https://docs.flutterflow.io/data-and-backend/firebase/firestore-database-cloud-firestore/retrieving-data#2.-querying-a-collection-on-a-listview) but in this way you will be returning a Future instead of a Stream. For which docs says

  > (Optional) By default, the result of this query will automatically refresh when the items are added/updated/deleted inside the collection. Checkmark the **Single Time Query**, to load the result only once and not refresh when any updates are made.

You can follow the template **[Robin.do](https://docs.flutterflow.io/miscellaneous/available-sample-apps)** and follow it’s walkthrough of creating it here : **[Performing CRUD operations](https://blog.flutterflow.io/cloud-firestore/#performing-crud-operations)**

Comment: Hello Rohit, I tried out Robin.do, and it seems to have the same issue I'm facing. The data list doesn't refresh automatically until I navigate to another screen. 
Also do you any reference which help to refresh list on state change ?